# Problem with inserting simple jekyll images

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I'm trying to get my first website with Github pages.  I read up on quite a few things about getting images to show up on my site but it appears the link is always broken!

[image]

Below is my Jekyll markdown.  The first image was how I expected it to work.  The second image I downloaded and copied it from a tutorial website but it also isn't showing up.

[image]

Below is a snapshot of my files if it matters.

[image]

Comment: Check the filename. Your link ends in `gardens.jpg`, but your file on disk appears to be `garden.jpg` (no 's')

Comment: You are totally correct, thank you.  I made the change, but nothing better :/

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** :
Now that your assets files are versioned, you have case sensitivity problems.

```
![shred](/assets/images/Shred.jpg)
```

must be :

```
![shred](/assets/images/shred.jpg)
```

and

```
![Philadelphia...](/assets/philly-magic-gardens.jpg "Philadelphia's Magic Gardens")
```

must be :

```
![Philadelphia...](/assets/philly-magic-garden.jpg "Philadelphia's Magic Gardens")
```

**End Edit**

You definitely need to commit your assets folder.

[image]

Comment: plus one for finding the github repo.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!  I committed the folders.  But it still isn't showing.  The jpg files are also in my GitHub repository.